# Connecting an Android device to a Windows network

Tags: wi-fi, networking, windows

Is it possible to connect my Android phone to my Vista network?

I want to add files in a shared folder which I can access over a wifi network on my phone.

I tried to add my phone to the network manually in the Network Center, but it didn't work.

A Google search didn't provide me anything useful.

Note: 
When on the wifi network with my phone, I am on the same network as my Vista machine

Answer (score 1):

Nice question I would be interested in the same. ES File Explorer looks like the app to do the trick.  Check this out...
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tablets/connect-android-to-windows-and-samba-shared-directories/1262

Answer (score 0):

Support for SMB ("Windows Network") is not native to Android. You will need [an app that supports the protocol.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en) I can't recommend a specific [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) app as I've never tried it on Android.

I will say that I prefer FTP'ing to my Android using [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [Software Data Cable](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyy.softdatacable&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5seXkuc29mdGRhdGFjYWJsZSJd). Software Data Cable is a little clunky, and I'm sure there's a better FTP app out there, but it's no big deal once FTP gets going. I don't really care for SMB, FTP has been much more robust in my personal experience.